# Printing large numbers with numeric suffix

Tags: number

Is there any LaTeX package that pretty-prints a large number with appropriate numeric suffix, e.g., `6260563 -> 6.2M`?

Comment: not 6.3M ?.....

Comment: l3fp (xfp) could handle the rounding to 2 significant figures, then you just need a lookup table of suffixes. You could probably coerce siunitx into doing this as it knows all the SI prefixes which is I assume what you are using as suffix here.

Comment: 6.3M would also do. Do you have an MWE please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THis is a simple version (rounding to 1 decimal place rather than 2 significant figures) and can't handle integers larger than the ones shown as it uses tex arithemetic in places. (I could probably do more in l3fp if larger values are needed)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\def\zz#1{%
\ifnum#1>1000000000
\fpeval{round(#1/1000000000,1)}G%
\else
\ifnum#1>1000000
\fpeval{round(#1/1000000,1)}M%
\else
\ifnum#1>1000
\fpeval{round(#1/1000,1)}K%
\else
#1%
\fi\fi\fi}

\def\test#1{\par#1 $\rightarrow$ \zz{#1}}

\begin{document}

\test{626}
\test{6260}
\test{62605}
\test{626056}
\test{6260563}
\test{62605631}
\test{626056312}
% \test{6260563123} too big


\end{document}
```

Comment: The last number rounds up to 6.3G as expected, but with the following message printed on log: `I can only go up to 2147483647='17777777777="7FFFFFFF,
so I'm using that number instead of yours.` Where is the bottleneck coming from?