# Latex complaining about large numbers

Tags: floating-point, xfp

To pretty print large numbers with numeric suffix, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618538/61804) solution works fine, except the last test case (the poster already indicated that, so it is not unexpected). Surprisingly, `6260563123` is correctly shortened to `6.3G`, but also the following message appears in the log:

> I can only go up to 2147483647='17777777777="7FFFFFFF, so I'm using
> that number instead of yours

Can anybody please guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: that is the range of tex count integers, you could use l3fp or xint or some other package doing the arithmetic "by hand" to get a larger  range

Comment: Ah, that was your solution I noticed :-) It worked for me previously, but now I have to deal with large numbers. Are you saying the `ifnum` comparison is the problem? I am a TeX n00b, so bear with me

Answer (score 2):

This supports all known prefixes and quite large numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\postfix}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \str_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    {1}{#1}
    {2}{#1}
    {3}{#1}
    {4}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 3 } { k }}
    {5}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 3 } { k }}
    {6}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 3 } { k }}
    {7}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 6 } { M }}
    {8}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 6 } { M }}
    {9}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 6 } { M }}
    {10}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 9 } { G }}
    {11}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 9 } { G }}
    {12}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 9 } { G }}
    {13}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 12 } { T }}
    {14}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 12 } { T }}
    {15}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 12 } { T }}
    {16}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 15 } { P }}
    {17}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 15 } { P }}
    {18}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 15 } { P }}
    {19}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 18 } { E }}
    {20}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 18 } { E }}
    {21}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 18 } { E }}
    {22}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 21 } { Z }}
    {23}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 21 } { Z }}
    {24}{\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 21 } { Z }}
   }
   {\hs_print:nnn { #1 } { 24 } { Y }}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \hs_print:nnn
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round(#1 / 10^(#2), 1) } #3
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand\test[1]{\par#1 ${}\rightarrow{}$ \postfix{#1}}

\begin{document}

\test{6}
\test{62}
\test{626}
\test{6260}
\test{62605}
\test{626056}
\test{6260563}
\test{62605631}
\test{626056312}
\test{6260563123}
\test{62605631234}
\test{626056312345}
\test{6260563123456}
\test{62605631234567}
\test{626056312345678}
\test{6260563123456789}
\test{62605631234567890}
\test{626056312345678901}
\test{6260563123456789012}
\test{62605631234567890123}
\test{626056312345678901234}
\test{6260563123456789012345}
\test{62605631234567890123456}
\test{626056312345678901234567}
\test{6260563123456789012345678}
\test{62605631234567890123456789}
\test{626056312345678901234567890}
\test{6260563123456789012345678901}
\test{62605631234567890123456789012}
\test{626056312345678901234567890123}
\test{6260563123456789012345678901234}
\test{62605631234567890123456789012345}
\test{626056312345678901234567890123456}
\test{6260563123456789012345678901234567}
\test{62605631234567890123456789012345678}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that can handle large numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,xintfrac}
\def\zz#1{%
\xintifGt{#1}{1000000000}{
    \fpeval{round(#1/1000000000, 1)}G%
}{\xintifGt{#1}{1000000}{
    \fpeval{round(#1/1000000, 1)}M%
}{\xintifGt{#1}{1000}{
    \fpeval{round(#1/1000, 1)}K%
}{
    #1%
}}}}

\def\test#1{\par#1 $\rightarrow$ \zz{#1}}

\begin{document}

\test{626}
\test{6260}
\test{62605}
\test{626056}
\test{6260563}
\test{62605631}
\test{626056312}
\test{6260563123}

\end{document}
```